# Table rows are hidden in chrome console element tab

Tags: selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-devtools

Our application is react and we have a table with more than 25 rows, but at a time it will load 25 rows as paginated. When I try to inspect the element and get the count of rows, I am getting only 20 or less from the console.  Is there anyway that we can change the browser settings to show the hidden content for all the rows that displayed in the application?

screenshot from the application shows I selected 25 records
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13FaI.png)

screenshot from the console
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14H6u.png)

```
<tbody class="MuiTableBody-root-717 jss661" style="display: table-row-group;">
   <tr class="jss674" aria-label="trade-data-row-lineitem-004-10540141-128-highlight" style="position: absolute; transform: translateY(0px); min-width: 100%; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
   </tr>
   <tr class="jss674" aria-label="trade-data-row-lineitem-004-10540141-619-highlight" style="position: absolute; transform: translateY(35px); min-width: 100%; background-color: rgb(235, 238, 241);"></tr>
   <tr class="jss674" aria-label="trade-data-row-lineitem-004-10540141-619-highlight" style="position: absolute; transform: translateY(35px); min-width: 100%; background-color: rgb(235, 238, 241);"></tr>
   <tr class="jss674" aria-label="trade-data-row-lineitem-004-10540141-619-highlight" style="position: absolute; transform: translateY(35px); min-width: 100%; background-color: rgb(235, 238, 241);"></tr>
   <tr class="jss674" aria-label="trade-data-row-lineitem-004-10540141-619-highlight" style="position: absolute; transform: translateY(35px); min-width: 100%; background-color: rgb(235, 238, 241);"></tr>
   <tr class="jss674" aria-label="trade-data-row-lineitem-004-10540141-619-highlight" style="position: absolute; transform: translateY(35px); min-width: 100%; background-color: rgb(235, 238, 241);"></tr>
   <tr class="jss674" aria-label="trade-data-row-lineitem-004-10540141-619-highlight" style="position: absolute; transform: translateY(35px); min-width: 100%; background-color: rgb(235, 238, 241);"></tr>
   <tr class="jss674" aria-label="trade-data-row-lineitem-004-10540141-619-highlight" style="position: absolute; transform: translateY(35px); min-width: 100%; background-color: rgb(235, 238, 241);"></tr>
   <tr class="jss674" aria-label="trade-data-row-lineitem-004-10540141-619-highlight" style="position: absolute; transform: translateY(35px); min-width: 100%; background-color: rgb(235, 238, 241);"></tr>
   <tr class="jss674" aria-label="trade-data-row-lineitem-004-10540141-619-highlight" style="position: absolute; transform: translateY(35px); min-width: 100%; background-color: rgb(235, 238, 241);"></tr>
   <tr class="jss674" aria-label="trade-data-row-lineitem-004-10540141-619-highlight" style="position: absolute; transform: translateY(35px); min-width: 100%; background-color: rgb(235, 238, 241);"></tr>
   <tr class="jss674" aria-label="trade-data-row-lineitem-004-10540141-619-highlight" style="position: absolute; transform: translateY(35px); min-width: 100%; background-color: rgb(235, 238, 241);"></tr>
   <tr class="jss674" aria-label="trade-data-row-lineitem-004-10540141-619-highlight" style="position: absolute; transform: translateY(35px); min-width: 100%; background-color: rgb(235, 238, 241);"></tr>
   <tr class="jss674" aria-label="trade-data-row-lineitem-004-10540141-619-highlight" style="position: absolute; transform: translateY(35px); min-width: 100%; background-color: rgb(235, 238, 241);"></tr>
   <tr class="jss674" aria-label="trade-data-row-lineitem-004-10540141-619-highlight" style="position: absolute; transform: translateY(35px); min-width: 100%; background-color: rgb(235, 238, 241);"></tr>
   <tr class="jss674" aria-label="trade-data-row-lineitem-004-10540141-619-highlight" style="position: absolute; transform: translateY(35px); min-width: 100%; background-color: rgb(235, 238, 241);"></tr>
   <tr class="jss674" aria-label="trade-data-row-lineitem-004-10540141-619-highlight" style="position: absolute; transform: translateY(35px); min-width: 100%; background-color: rgb(235, 238, 241);"></tr>
   <tr class="jss674" aria-label="trade-data-row-lineitem-004-10540141-619-highlight" style="position: absolute; transform: translateY(35px); min-width: 100%; background-color: rgb(235, 238, 241);"></tr>
   <tr class="jss674" aria-label="trade-data-row-lineitem-004-10540141-619-highlight" style="position: absolute; transform: translateY(35px); min-width: 100%; background-color: rgb(235, 238, 241);"></tr>
   <tr class="jss674" aria-label="trade-data-row-lineitem-004-10540141-619-highlight" style="position: absolute; transform: translateY(35px); min-width: 100%; background-color: rgb(235, 238, 241);"></tr>
```

I checked with my developers, and they said it is something to do with the browser as it is blocking by the browser.

Comment: What you describe either can't happen or it's a bug in devtools. Devtools always shows the actual contents of DOM. Your html contains 20 rows. Please provide an [MCVE](/help/mcve) or at least a link to the actual site.

Comment: sorry, I can't provide site details. for sample code I have provided the screenshots of how it looks like. Also provided the sample code above. The application is react so it renders only when you load more data and also when I scroll down the tr tags at the top will be hidden and get new tr tags for the recent data loaded at the bottom

Comment: Without an [MCVE](/help/mcve) there's nothing to go on.